# How to avoid having air bubbles in clutch line after cylinder replacement?

Tags: brake-fluid, clutch-cylinder

I am in the process of replacing the clutch master cylinder on my `2007 v6 Tacoma`.  When I detached the old one, I tried to minimize the leakage of the brake fluid.  Once I put the new part in and add more brake fluid, how should I make sure that the system is bled out of air and there are no air bubbles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bleeding procedure is the same as it would be for a hydraulic brake system.

There is a nipple on the master cylinder to bleed out fluid and air, same as a brake caliper.

1. Pump the clutch to build up pressure (keep clutch depressed)
2. Open the nipple/valve on the master cylinder
3. Allow fluid/air to escape from the nipple/valve
4. Close nipple/valve on master cylinder
5. Remove pressure from clutch
6. Pump clutch......
7. Wash/rinse/repeat above procedure until no more air is coming out of the master cylinder nipple/valve

BE SURE THE RESERVOIR ALWAYS HAS BRAKE FLUID IN IT

That's it, very simple, same as brakes.  Good luck!

**EDIT:**

The nipple is located on the slave cylinder. The slave cylinder should be located towards the bottom of the transmission at the bell housing. You are looking for something which looks like this:

[image: Image pulled from rockauto.com]

The brass fitting is what you'd be using to do the bleed. Obviously, the hose which you'd follow down from the master cylinder would be attached to this but is not shown in the picture.

Comment: `Open the nipple/valve on the master cylinder`, do you mean the brake fluid tank into which you pour brake fluid?

Comment: @amphibient There should be a little nipple on the slave cylinder which is attached to the transmission. You will need to find that to bleed the clutch.

Comment: so that is somewhere under where the stick shift is on the inside, correct ?

Comment: I hope you don't mind I added what I did, Ducati. Hopefully it clarifies things for the OP.

Comment: For clarity, you should probably add a "close nipple" step before letting off the clutch pedal (between 3 & 4). Somewhat related, some clutches are gravity-bled...

Comment: One trick I was once told - If the master and slave cylinders are both accessible from within the engine bay, attach a length of clear pipe to the slave cylinder bleed nipple, then stick the other side into the master cylinder reservoir, so that the fluid being bled out of the system goes straight back in, but without the air bubbles. Much less wastage... (Don't do this on brakes though, for safety reasons, and logical ones...)

Comment: this is my newest related question, I would appreciate answers:  http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16756/new-clutch-master-cylinder-not-filling-with-fluid-after-replacement